# Дуплексив, синкретизм

Tags: синтаксис

В Интернете встретил предложение с дуплексивом. Но не могу разобраться, где дуплексив.

> Мне приходится первому открывать огонь, когда японцы подходят с севера (А. Степанов);

Разбираю так: Я первым открываю огонь.  Я (какой?первый,каким?) первым - определение и открываю (как?)обст. Но не уверен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вам так удобно, то так.

> Мне приходится *(какому? как?)* первому открывать огонь, когда японцы подходят с севера (А. Степанов);

Приходится открывать огонь **кому?** — мне (дополнение), **какому?**  — первому (определение).

Приходится открывать огонь **как?** — первому (обстоятельство).

Comment: Спасибо, значит, правильно увидел.